# Is part of a circle lying on first quadrant?

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, circles

I have  circle $ C: (x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2\leq r^2$ with center $(x_0,y_0)$ and radius $r$.

I want to find out in exactly what quadrants the circle lies. Is there a condition with this functionality?

i.e if the cirlce lies exclusively in the first quadrant what condition should hold truth?

i.e If the circle lies in first and second quadrant what condition should hold truth?

Comment: a circle or a closed disk

Comment: circle and all inner points of the circle

Comment: If $C$ is to lie exclusively in the first quadrant then $x_0-r> 0$ and $y_0-r>0$.

Comment: @eloiPrime What if $C$ lies on first and second quadrant and the center of circle is on the second quadrant. In this case how can I check if there are points of $C$ in the first quadrant?

Comment: $C$ is to lie exclusively in the first and second quadrants if and only if $x_0 + r>0$, $x_0 - r<0$ and $y_0 -r > 0$. Note that the converse of my statement above is also true.

Comment: **Hint:** For first quadrant: Take $r = \min\{x_0,y_0\}$, with $x_0 , y_0 > 0$

Comment: I agree with eloiPrime for the two answers.

Answer (score 1):

Just note that $x_0 > r$ would imply the circle was entirely to the right of the $y$-axis, similarly $y_0 > r$ would imply the circle was entirely to the above the $x$-axis. Extend this logic and the solution falls out.